# how to insert into deeply nested element API nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nested

I have 4 nested documents as follow:

```
//Nested sub document subControl
const SubControlSchema = new Schema({
   subControlNo: {
     type: String
   },
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

//Nested sub document control
const ControlSubSchema = new Schema({

  mainControl: {
    type: String
  },
  subControls: [SubControlSchema],
  controlDescription: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

//Nested sub document domain
const DomainSubSchema = new Schema({
   _id: {
     type: Schema.ObjectId,
     auto: true
   },
   domainNo: {
     type: String,
    trim: true
   },
   domainName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
   },
  domainDescription: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  controls: [ControlSubSchema],
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
// framework Schema
const FrameworkSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  regulator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Regulator',
    default: null
  },
  client: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client',
    default: null
  },
  domains: [DomainSubSchema],
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('Framework', FrameworkSchema);
```

I'm trying to post a control under the domain which is inside the framework, here's what I have been trying to do:

```
//Add new control under a specific domain and framework
router.post('/add/:frameworkId/:domainId', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const control = req.body.controls; //take the request from the body
    const query = { _id: req.params.frameworkId, _id: req.params.domainId };//pushing into the framework model by taking the ID from URL

    await Framework.updateOne(query, { $push: { domains: control } }).exec(); //push the query into the framework model

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      controls: control
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
    // error: 'Your request could not be processed. Please try again.'
    error
    });
  }
});
```

Data posted in postman:

```
Link: http://localhost:3000/api/framework/add/6233277f411377367f8ad1c0/6233277f411377367f8ad1c1
{
    "controls":
{
      "mainControl": "1-5",
      "subControls": [{
      "subControlNo": "1-4-1"
    },
    {
    "subControlNo": "1-4-2"
    }],
    "controlDescription": "controlDescriptionTest"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "controls": {
        "mainControl": "1-5",
        "subControls": [
            {
                "subControlNo": "1-4-1"
            },
            {
                "subControlNo": "1-4-2"
            }
        ],
        "controlDescription": "controlDescriptionTest"
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I'm not getting any new data in mongodb , any idea if I'm approaching this the correct way? I'm guessing the data is posted correctly and It's a problem with saving it to the database

Picture of my schema: I want to be able to add elements under the controls:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First if you want your code to `insert` and not `update` you should use `insertOne` and not `updateOne`, regarding an "update" operation I can see 2 potential "issues" here:

1. `req.params.frameworkId` and `req.params.domainId` come as `string` type. And I assume the `_id` field is type `ObjectId` and not `string`.
   To fix this you just need to cast it to the proper type, like so:

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
...
{ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.frameworkId) }
```

2. Both parameters are "querying" the same field (`_id`), unless this is intentional somehow if these values are different it will never find a document to match, this should be changed.

Lastly if you want to update an existing object if exists, and if not insert then you should use `updateOne` with the `upsert` option:

```
await Framework.updateOne(query, { $push: { domains: control } }, { upsert: true }).exec();
```

Comment: thank you,, these points are great I'll work on them, But it doesn't answer my question, how can I reach the domain control under the framework to insert the new object control?

Comment: Your code is fine and will push the "control" to the domain array if all other issues are fixed.